# LiveScript - How do I use the backcall operator when there are multiple callbacks?

Tags: javascript, livescript

For example:

```
$.get('/path/to/api').then(
  function(data) {
    alert( "$.get succeeded" );
  }, function(error) {
    alert( "$.get failed!" );
  }
);
```

Is it possible to apply the backcall operator on both callbacks?

Comment: What is a ``backcall operator``?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use one function with the backcall, but what you can do is use a backcall, and supply the other function normally (note the use of the `_` as a placeholder to denote where the backcall function should go in the arguments) - eg.

```
data <- $.get '/path/to/api' .then _, -> alert "$.get failed!"
alert "$.get succeeded"
```

compiles to:

```
$.get('/path/to/api').then(function(data){
  return alert("$.get succeeded");
}, function(){
  return alert("$.get failed!");
});
```

Comment: Wow, did I just get LiveScript author's first SO answer? Many thanks! =D